# Tarski-Vaught Test with languages without constants

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory, quantifiers

Does the Tarski-Vaught Test apply to structures of languages that do not contain any constants? From the proofs I've tried to find in textbooks, it relies on quantifier elimination which also relies on the language having constants. Thanks.

Comment: In what sense does quantifier elimination rely on constants? And in what sense does Tarski-Vaught rely on quantifier elimination?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I conjecture that by "constants" OP means the $0$-ary connectives $\top$ and $\bot$, which are sometimes called propositional constants, and which are used in quantifier elimination. (I have no conjecture abut how Tarski-Vaught might rely on quantifier elimination.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I meant constant symbols like $\mathbb{0}$ in number theory and I thought they were necessary to show every formula can be constructed inductively to an equivalent formula with only one existential quantifier to fit the statement of the test.

Comment: @Ari Tarski-Vaught does **not** say or require that every formula be equivalent to an existential one. I think you may be mixing up Tarski-Vaught and model completeness (which is a weak form of quantifier elimination).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yeah I guess that's it. I was just thrown off my the proof technique of the textbook. So just to confirm, there are no restrictions on the language of the structure to apply the Tarski-Vaught test, is that correct?

Comment: The Tarski-Vaught test applies to first-order languages of every type.